# Reminders are not Triggering on Correct Time

Tags: java, android, reminders

Reminders are not triggering on correct time, triggers only when I Reboot my device.

A day when I created Reminder, same day I was getting it on correct time, but after that it triggers only when I restart my device (not on correct time which I have chosen).

Like, I have created 5 different Reminders - one to trigger everyday, second to trigger on every 2 day, third to trigger on every 3rd day, fourth to trigger Weekly and fifth to trigger Monthly

But whenever I restart my device they all triggers on same time (like If I restart my device at :05:00, then they all triggers at same time), whereas I was expecting Eye Drop to trigger on 12:15, Cyrip to trigger at 13:20 on every 2nd day and so on.

**AlarmReceiver.java:**

```
public void setRepeatAlarm(Context context, Calendar calendar, int ID, long RepeatTime) {
    mAlarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    // Put Reminder ID in Intent Extra
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra(ReminderEditActivity.EXTRA_REMINDER_ID, Integer.toString(ID));
    mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, ID, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    // Calculate notification timein
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    long currentTime = c.getTimeInMillis();
    long diffTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis() - currentTime;

    // Start alarm using initial notification time and repeat interval time
    mAlarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
            SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + diffTime,
            RepeatTime , mPendingIntent);

    // Restart alarm if device is rebooted
    ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, BootReceiver.class);
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
}
```

Comment: Check you ID, from   mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, ID, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT); You might override the other alarms and set only 1. If you set an older alarm it should not interfere with the other, but the ID s you set for them will

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you (re)create the alarms (for example in the boot receiver) you must adjust the date, by adding repeat intervals, until the date is in the future.

Currently you are recreating the alarms with the same parameters. It only works until the first trigger time is reached. After that on each reboot you are giving the alarm manager a date in the past, so the alarm is triggered immediately.

**edit**:

For example in `setRepeatAlarm()` you could :

```
// Calculate notification timein
...
long diffTime = ...

// ensure the next alarm is in the future
while(diffTime < 0) {
    diffTime += RepeatTime;
}
```

Comment: yeah I think you are right.... but may I know how can I control this to get my reminders triggers on time only.

Comment: so you mean finally my setRepeatAlarm() method will look like the one I posted above, see UPDATED section

Comment: exactly, and for a non repeating alarm, just not recreate it if `diffTime` is negative

Comment: thank you so much :) I took a day to test my reminders functionality, and you will be happy that it works just perfect, thank you so much (bounty + accept + useful) this is what I can reward you and I did. One more thing I need your help once again, I added another column as select end date, storing that date into database along with other reminder details, so may I know how to perform remove reminder functionality based on end date chosen for reminder....

Comment: You can check, each time an alarm is triggered, if the next time is beyond the end date, something like
`nowCalendar.getTimeInMillis() + repeatTime > endCalendar.getTimeInMillis()`, and if so, cancel it.

It may be simpler to handle the repetition yourself, i.e. use only non repeating alarms and schedule the next one every time.
This is what you need to do anyway if you want to use exact alarms on API 19+ (there is no more exact repeating alarms)

Comment: Hey.. have a look at the issue, facing due to diffTime += RepeatTime;  I hope you can provide me the solution because you better know then anyone else http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37201956/it-is-not-under-singleton-mode-u-cant-use-it